# Android Studio on Chromebook, does not recognise itself as a device

Tags: android, android-studio, google-chrome-os, chromebook, androidappsonchromeos

I need to install an app, from my project to my Chromebook.
Now:

```
1. I have set developers mode ON
2. I have installed Android Studio.
3. I cloned the project, and it builds successfully.
4. I have installed adb on it.
```

BUT I still cannot run, cause it does not recognise my Chromebook as a "Connected Device"
Up, near the RUN icon it just says "No Devices" why is this?

This is my SDK Manager:
[image]

## EDIT:

I connected a Pixel 3 to my ChromeBook. I've pressed on "connect to linux" And I can run app on it. BUT still does not recognize my chromebook as a device to run on

Comment: you need to install a universal driver..here is the link--> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sRVNQ1SaOzI

Comment: Google Web Driver is installed. Google USB Driver is not in that list :-?
Also if I select "Android Emulator" and tick it, then press apply, It just unchecks it without downloading anythng :-?

Comment: that's why im saying refer the video to install google usb driver

Comment: @Wini I have EDITED my answer, if possible, please check the screenshot attached. As I said, I don't have USB Driver in the list of SDK Tools. Which is weird . I am running latest version of Android Studio, downloaded today

Comment: here I found one way...try downloading that-->https://developer.android.com/studio/run/win-usb

Comment: It's on the Chrome OS, not Windows. So doesn't work like that. Also, I can run on my Pixel3. So the USB driver should work, so I don't think that is the issue

Answer (score 1):

I have had encountered same issue that adb only recognizes usb connected real devices but not Chromebook(AcerSpin 713) itself. To resolve this issue, Go to Settings > Apps > Google Play Store > Manage Android Preferences and enable Developer mode as you do on real android device.